# Javascript Stops Running Past $(.class).html(result)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which loads a group of products from a category when the .expandproducts button is clicked:

```
$('.expandproducts').click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    urlajax = document.location.origin + "/ajaxproducts?category=" + id;
    $.ajax({url: urlajax, success: function(result){
        $("." + id).html(result);
        //code seems to stop here! Cannot figure out why YAY is not displayed, no errors in console.
        alert("Yay");
    }});
})
```

The ajax side seems to work fine and content is loaded into the div via ajax. My ID is taken from the button and loads the correct category from my controller and puts into correct containing div on my page however any functions i add after `$("." + id).html(result);` just do not fire so `alert("Yay");` does not work.

I cannot see any errors in the log and am confused as to why this is and wondering if anyone else can suggest what i may have done wrong?

Ok this snippet works but i put it here anyway:

```js
$('.expandproducts').click(function(){
  id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  urlajax = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + id;
  $.ajax({url: urlajax, success: function(result){
   result = "result: " + result;
      $(".container-" + id).html(result);
      //code seems to stop here! Cannot figure out why YAY is not displayed, no errors in console.
   alert("Yay");
  }});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Products load under here:</p><button data-id="1" class="expandproducts">EXPAND</button>
<div class="container-1">
</div>
```

Why would this not work in my context?

Comment: don't add function inside `$.ajax`. add outside of it. Please be more clear about what you want to add and what is not working. Also add some sort of html for more clearnece of your problem

Comment: any error in ur console? I believe the id is null since ur declare out of ajax?

Comment: You are not reloading page properly , hard refresh `Ctrl+F5`, This could be the problem.

Comment: ID is fine it loads the content. I just need to add a function after the content is loaded running outisde of ajax runs it before.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh It's $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart(); that i actually want to run but for simplicity i have used alert("Yay"); and that also does not work. Outside of the ajax function leads to the function running before content loaded and so my function runs before its needed too

Comment: @Se0ng11 Id is not null this is an id taken from the expand button of a category and is present on page load.

Comment: `$("form[data-role='tocart-form']")` already exist in dom or added through  the code`$("." + id).html(result);` ?

Comment: the forms are added as add to cart buttons in ajax result. They will exist in the dom already however if a previous category expanded. First tho i want to get a simple function like alert("yay") as if this doesn't fire either then anything else is not going to work either.

Comment: put console.log(id) or console.log(result) before ("." + id).html(result); and check in ur console whether it log some result in ur console

Comment: Yeah absolutely fine get my id and result. As stated the content is loaded fine which needs the id to select the container its loaded into and for the controller to generate the correct category content.

Comment: Seems like the error is somewhere else. I made a JSFiddle which works, https://jsfiddle.net/fr9nxeg6/

Comment: Yeah i have done the same. And it works. https://jsfiddle.net/eyxq9gqu/8/

Comment: Not sure why javascript stops in my function tho it continues outside of the ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying

> It seems to work prefectly and content is loaded into the div via ajax

You are not reloading page properly , hard refresh page by `Ctrl+F5`, This could be the problem.

Except `reloading issue` there is no issue here.

Or It might be with your ajax content issue.

Comment: Well I do not want to reload the page this is loading content via ajax and so is not necessary.

Comment: c + f5 loads all content of page again, it will load files freshly(may be your scrip file is taken from cache).
Look at page source, check your changes are rendering.

Comment: @harri: I am saying to reload page to get value from db, Just refresh once. and get value by ajax to reflect you code that you added `alert('Yay')`

Comment: Yeah i have refreshed the page many a time i can see my alert("yay") is present in script.

Comment: @harri : what if you put `alert` before `.html()` ?

Comment: Yeah runs fine. I have tried after the ajax function and its fine also. Seems to stop because of the result that is added to a div.

Comment: and when you hard code value of `result`  I mean try something like `$("." + id).html('Testing');`

Comment: can you share how and what value you are getting from ajax ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the troubleshooting. My controller was spitting out a lot more than i intended ive stripped it right out and now everything is fine!

Comment: I would change your answer a little to state that my result must be causing issues with your script and ill accept as an answer

Comment: @harri : I updated my answer , you can also update my answer is nedded, Now you can accept my answer